# How to derive the inclination angle evolution of a dipolar pulsar?

Tags: magnetic-fields, rotational-dynamics, torque, dipole, pulsars

The spin-down evolution of a simple vacuum pulsar model is well known.  Using the power output of radiation emission of a rotating magnetic dipole, we get the following equation (assuming that the rotation kinetic energy loss equals the electromagnetic power emitted by the rotating dipole) :
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\frac{d\,}{dt} \Big( \frac{1}{2} \, I \, \omega^2 \Big) = I \, \omega \, \dot{\omega} = -\, \frac{\mu_0 \, \mu^2 \, \omega^4}{6 \pi c^3} \, \sin^2{\alpha},
\end{equation}
where $\alpha$ is the tilt (or inclination) angle of the pulsar's magnetic axis, relative to the rotation axis.

I'm interested in a similar equation for the time evolution of the tilt angle :
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\dot{\alpha} = \; .?.
\end{equation}
According to this paper : https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.01487, we should have this equation (see equation (2) from that article) :
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
I \, \dot{\alpha} = -\, \frac{\mu_0 \, \mu^2 \, \omega^2}{6 \pi c^3} \, \sin{\alpha} \, \cos{\alpha}.
\end{equation}
How to demonstrate this equation ?

And how to show that the time variation of the angular momentum (relative to the magnetic moment ?) has the following components ?
\begin{align}\tag{4}
& I \, \frac{d\omega}{d \, t},
&& I \, \omega \, \frac{d \, \alpha}{d \, t}.
\end{align}
I understand only the first component, which is obvious to me, while the second is not.

Comment: Can you access the following links from the SAO/NASA server?  [Davis & Goldstein 1970](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1970ApJ...159L..81D), [Michel & Goldwire 1970](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1970ApL.....5...21M)

Comment: The short answer seems to be "calculate the torque by integrating the Maxwell stress tensor appropriately over the surface of the star."

Comment: Hmm, the calculations are very laborious, and I don't get the *tilt torque* part (equation (3) above).  Only the standard angular part (equation (1)).  Paper http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1970ApJ...159L..81D/L000081.000.html states that the equation (3) could also be derived from symmetry and equation (1) (see the first page).  I don't get it.